# How to prevent values on get from reset when press submit button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I work on razor page asp.net . I face issue my issue values on get reset after click submit button so  when click submit button and check values on POST I found it become null

so How to avoid this behavior  OR with another meaning how to retain values on get without reset when click submit button

from my debug details as below

1 - when page load i check user id it have value 9595

```
   public void OnGet()
    {
        string MyUserData = Request.Cookies["myUserData"];
        UserAuthResponse? userAuthResponse = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserAuthResponse>(MyUserData);
        string UserID = userAuthResponse.Data.UserID;
    }
```

2 - Now I will click submit button so break point hit on post method

```
public async Task OnPost(UC.ADC.Core.Entities.SQL.Branch branch)
{
//userAuthResponse.Data.UserID become null
}
```

when check values of `userAuthResponse.Data.UserID` it become null

**so how to preserve or retain value of `userAuthResponse.Data.UserID` after make get
to use it on post method**

form view as below :

```
<form method="post">
       
        <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left:200px;font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">
            <button type="submit" class="col-sm-1 btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            
        </div>
    </form>
```

issue debug details as below :

[image: issue debug details]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a public property to your PageModel class that represents the value and apply a `BindProperty` attribute to it. Then add a hidden field to your form that contains the value you want to persist across requests:

```
[BindProperty]
public string UserID {get;set;}
public void OnGet()
{
    string MyUserData = Request.Cookies["myUserData"];
    UserAuthResponse? userAuthResponse = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserAuthResponse>(MyUserData);
    UserID = userAuthResponse.Data.UserID;
}
```

Then the form:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="UserID" />
    <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left:200px;font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">
        <button type="submit" class="col-sm-1 btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The posted value should automatically get bound to the public property.

This is one of many state management strategies for persisting values across HTTP requests: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/state-management